# A little js exercise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html:

```html
<div id="foo">
 <span class="bar">text</span>
<div>
```

And here is my question:

How can I make the `text` coloured red using JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: `$('#foo span.bar').css('color', 'red')`

Comment: You can do it with CSS or HTML... Easier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** in jquery

```
$("#foo span").css("color",'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `css()` for the change of color, here is a sample example using a button to change the css for the text you require.

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
  $(".bar").css("color", "red");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
 <span class="bar">text</span>
  <input id="clickme" type="button" value="clickme"> </input>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a class in css something like this:

```
//foo.css
.red: {
  color: red;
}
```

and with jQuery:

```
$('#foo span").addClass('red');
```

add the class to the element!

Answer (score 0):

use This :

```
$(".bar").css("color","red");
```